# Monitoring list item fields for a certain span of time

Tags: splistitem, monitoring

how to monitor a list item field or document library metadata for a duration of say 20 days whether it was modified or not. (tracking only one field not the entire list item modified date)

the purpose here is to notify the users with an email that they haven't acted on the case since last 20 days.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **Custom Timer Job** which will monitor the items. Just compare the current date and item modified field. For example

```
var lastModified = (DateTime.Now - (DateTime) item["Modified"]).Days;
```

If the duration is greater than or equal to 20 days, then take action. Steps of creating **Custom Timer Job** for on-premise, find here [Create and Deploy Custom Timer Job Definition in SharePoint Programatically](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S)

For **SharePoint Online**, you can write a **Console Application** which will contain the same logic as **Custom Timer Job** but run this **Console Application** using windows scheduler.

Comment: This is not what i am looking for. I want to know when the specific list item field was modified not the modified field which is linked to change in any field.

Comment: It was not clear to me since your last edit. Sorry it's my bad! @kesava